# Найти столбцы по части именования и построить DataFrame

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

У меня есть задача на основе ежедневных прайсов (xls) получить DataFrame, который будет исходником для формирования последующих данных.

Проблема в постоянных изменениях наименований столбцов и их расположений по горизонтали. В именовании столбцов есть всегда какая-либо постоянная, к которой я и хочу привязаться. Столбцов может быть много. Мне по сути надо вычленить столбец,  у которого наименование содержит
 "Артикул", "Наименование", "Прайс" | Вхождение в данных встречается один раз на весь файл с данными.
Номер строки, в которой содержатся именования столбцов - постоянный.

Например три вариации ежедневного прайса, с которым приходится работать:

[image: Три вариации]

Мне нужно построить конструкцию, при которой конечный dataframe будет содержать три столбца с данными:

> Артикул  Наименование  Прайс

[файлы-примеры](https://yadi.sk/d/Ulwn6wU93YHjGV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

решение:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

def parse_xl(filename, canonic_cols=['артикул','наименование','прайс'], **kwargs):
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, **kwargs)
    d = {df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(col, flags=re.I)][0] : col
         for col in canonic_cols}
    return df.rename(columns=d)[canonic_cols]

# "каноническое" наименование столбцов (должно встречаться в качестве подстрок в именах столбцов)
# порядок столбцов в результирующем DF также задается данным списком
canonic_cols=['артикул','наименование','прайс']

df = parse_xl(filename, canonic_cols)
```

проверка:

```
In [52]: parse_xl(r'D:\download\1.xls')
Out[52]:
  артикул наименование  прайс
0    а123      Товар А    100
1    б123      Товар Б    200
2    в123      Товар В    300

In [53]: parse_xl(r'D:\download\2.xls')
Out[53]:
  артикул наименование  прайс
0    a123      Товар А    100
1    б123      Товар Б    200
2    в123      Товар В    300

In [54]: parse_xl(r'D:\download\3.xls')
Out[54]:
  артикул наименование  прайс
0    а123      Товар А    100
1    б123      Товар Б    200
2    в123      Товар В    300
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я и не сомневался, что поможет @MaxU 
Понял, что в этой среде без регулярных выражений вообще никуда.

Comment: @APmansib, рад был помочь :) Регулярные выражения здесь используются только для регистронезависимого поиска. Но в общем вы правильно сказали - использование регулярных выражений сильно упрощает решения...