# Как добавлять в DataFrame данные из разных столбцов Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Есть задача, собрать из нескольких файлов Excel с разной структурой данных один фрейм с определенной структурой.

Пусть будет так:

Таблица-1:

```
A      B    C       D
Города  ФИО  Телефон Адрес
Москва  ААА  1111111 XXXXXXXX
Химки   ААБ  1111112 XXXXXXXZ
Лобня   ААВ  1111113 XXXXXXXY
```

Таблица-2:

```
A   B      C        D
ИМЯ Город  Phone    Почтовый индекс
БББ Рязань 22222222 00000000
ББВ Руза   22222223 00000001
ББГ Актау  22222224 00000002
```

Таблица-3:

```
A       B     C   D      E
Тел     Город ФИО Email  Дата
3333333 Оскол ВВВ a@a.ru 23.05.2019
3333334 Орёл  ВВГ b@a.ru 24.05.2019
3333335 Омск  ВВД c@a.ru 25.05.2019
```

Во фрейм с такой структурой

Фрейм:

```
Tel     Name City   Email
1111111 ААА  Москва
1111112 ААБ  Химки  
1111113 ААВ  Лобня  
2222222 БББ  Рязань
2222223 ББВ  Руза
2222224 ББГ  Актау
3333333 ВВВ  Оскол  a@a.ru
3333334 ВВГ  Орёл   b@a.ru
3333335 ВВД  Омск   c@a.ru
```

Использую:

```py
df.columns = ['Tel', 'Name', 'City', 'Email']

df = pd.read_excel(path, header=0, usecols="A,B,C,D", encoding='utf8')
```

Естественно данные перемешиваются во фрейме, потому что в разных файлах разный порядок столбцов с данными.

Как в этом случае быть?

Курил мануалы по Pandas на русском, потом на английском, но или я что то пропустил, или этой инфы нет. Хотя я уверен что она есть.

Как читать данные из определенных столбцов файлов, и записывать их в определенный столбец фрейма. Да я знаю что `usecols="A,B,C,D"` это и есть указание какие стоблцы читать, но вопрос как упорядочить данные из столбцов?

Comment: я правильно понимаю что данные связаны позицией строки в Excel файле? Например первая строка данных __во всех__ файлах относится к `a@a.ru`, вторая к другому конкретному пользователю и т.д.?

Comment: Нет, зависимостей строк нет. Мне просто нужно собрать из n-файлов данные из разных столбцов в один файл с нужной мне структурой(порядок столбцов).
Проблема в том что я не могу собрать в один фрейм данные, так как порядок столбцов разный в разных файлах.

Comment: Вот  Вы уже отвечали похоже на мой вопрос, только тут  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/845712/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-dataframe/845786#845786  наименования столбцов всегда одинаковые в файлах, порядок разный. А у меня наименования разные и количество и порядок столбцов разное. Изменил пример таблиц в коде тут для наглядности.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю при чтении файлов нормализовать ("привести к общему знаменателю") наименования столбцов:

Например:

```
mapping = {
  "Телефон": "Tel",
  "Phone": "Tel",
  "Тел": "Tel",
  "ФИО": "Name",
  "ИМЯ": "Name",
  "Города": "City",
  "Город": "City",
}

d1 = pd.read_excel("file1.xlsx").rename(columns=mapping)
d2 = pd.read_excel("file2.xlsx").rename(columns=mapping)
...
```

Для переименования столбцов можно также воспользоваться регулярными выражениями

В итоге получатся следующие DataFrame's:

```
In [32]: d1
Out[32]:
     City Name      Tel     Адрес
0  Москва  ААА  1111111  XXXXXXXX
1   Химки  ААБ  1111112  XXXXXXXZ
2   Лобня  ААВ  1111113  XXXXXXXY

In [33]: d2
Out[33]:
  Name    City       Tel  Почтовый_индекс
0  БББ  Рязань  22222222                0
1  ББВ    Руза  22222223                1
2  ББГ   Актау  22222224                2

In [34]: d3
Out[34]:
       Tel   City Name   Email        Дата
0  3333333  Оскол  ВВВ  a@a.ru  23.05.2019
1  3333334   Орёл  ВВГ  b@a.ru  24.05.2019
2  3333335   Омск  ВВД  c@a.ru  25.05.2019
```

Теперь их можно легко объединить и выбрать только интересующие нас столбцы:

```
In [35]: cols = ['Tel', 'Name', 'City', 'Email']

In [36]: res = pd.concat([df for df in [d1, d2, d3]], sort=False)[cols]

In [37]: res
Out[37]:
        Tel Name    City   Email
0   1111111  ААА  Москва     NaN
1   1111112  ААБ   Химки     NaN
2   1111113  ААВ   Лобня     NaN
0  22222222  БББ  Рязань     NaN
1  22222223  ББВ    Руза     NaN
2  22222224  ББГ   Актау     NaN
0   3333333  ВВВ   Оскол  a@a.ru
1   3333334  ВВГ    Орёл  b@a.ru
2   3333335  ВВД    Омск  c@a.ru
```

Comment: Max, вы наверно не видели мой ответ на свой вопрос? Я решил написать ответом в продолжение)

Comment: @ЕвгенийДолбановский, если вам удобнее указывать позиции столбцов вместо переименования столбцов - указывайте позиции столбцов. Как объединить DataFrame'ы с различными столбцами я уже показал в своем ответе. По-моему я уже ответил на ваш вопрос... Если у вас возникают ошибки, то откройте новый вопрос и приведите в нем код, пример данных и полный `error traceback`, чтобы было понятно что за ошибка и когда она возникает...

Comment: Я пока комбинирую разные методы, ваш однозначно лучший! Теперь затык в другом, не могу соединить 2 датафрейма по загрузке файлов по кнопке. Не сохраняется информация в  промежуточном фрейме. То есть по нажатии кнопки загружается первый файл, обрабатывается, функция заканчивается без return. По нажатии этой кнопки для выбора 2-го файла запускается та же функция, и получается что датафрейм обнуляется. Нужно через return передать результат в другую функцию к которой и делать .concat(). Я на верном пути, или нет?

Comment: @MaxU! 
а как копировать  IPYTHON в stackowerflow?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, не совсем понял вопрос... Вы имеете ввиду как парсить вывод в DataFrame или как запостить вывод на SO?