# Как пропустить отсутствующий столбец в Pandas при формировании DataFrame?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Пробую так:

```
mapping = {
    "Артикул ": "artikul_1",
    "Артикул аналог": "artikul_2",
    "Свободный остаток": "in_stock",
    "Номенклатура": "desc",
    "Город": "сity",
}

dfs = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.read_excel(file_excel_path, header=0, encoding='utf8').rename(columns=mapping)
dfs.append(df)
cols = ['artikul_1', 'artikul_2', 'in_stock', 'city']
df_fin = pd.concat([df for df in [df, dfs]], ignore_index=True, sort=False)[cols]
print(df_fin)
df_fin.to_excel('output_local.xlsx', index=False)
```

Но возникает ошибка из-за отсутствующего столбца:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:/CODE/Python/my_parser/gui_ostatki_pandas.py", line 147, in load_local_file_excel
df_fin = pd.concat([df for df in [df, dfs]], ignore_index=True, sort=False)[cols]
File "C:\CODE\Python\my_parser\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2934, in __getitem__
raise_missing=True)
File "C:\CODE\Python\my_parser\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1354, in _convert_to_indexer
return self._get_listlike_indexer(obj, axis, **kwargs)[1]
File "C:\CODE\Python\my_parser\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1161, in _get_listlike_indexer
raise_missing=raise_missing)
File "C:\CODE\Python\my_parser\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1252, in _validate_read_indexer
raise KeyError("{} not in index".format(not_found))
KeyError: "['city'] not in index"
```

Попробовал пример из совета уважаемого @MaxU: [Как добавлять в DataFrame данные из разных столбцов Excel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/984427/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-dataframe-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2-excel)

Сейчас пробую воспроизвести его пример, но не пойму в чем ошибка.

Нужно сформировать DataFrame со столбцами в определенном порядке, но не в каждом загружаемом файле есть нужные столбцы. Как пропустить отсутствующие?

Тестовые файлы: https://yadi.sk/d/_EWMHK9uo9KWsg.

Файлы в названии которых tab это файлы сделанные для проверки примера от @MaxU вот по этой ссылке решение было для этих файлов: [Как добавлять в DataFrame данные из разных столбцов Excel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/984427/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-dataframe-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2-excel)

Не работает. @MaxU привел пример и он работает как я так понял в iPython, а вот в Pycharm нет.

---

UPD1

Получилось обойти ошибку, явно указав структуру пустого `DataFrame`, который создаётся как общий фрейм для данных из всех файлов, но `dfs.append(df)` не работает, не происходит слияние `DataFrame`, просто происходит замена и всё.

```
mapping = {
    "Артикул ": "artikul_1",
    "Артикул аналог": "artikul_2",
    "Свободный остаток": "in_stock",
    "Номенклатура": "desc",
    "Москва": "сity",
}

dfs = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['artikul_1', 'artikul_2', 'price_max', 'in_stock', 'city', 'desc'])
df = pd.read_excel(file_excel_path, header=0,  encoding='utf8').rename(columns=mapping)

dfs = dfs.append(df)

print('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
print(dfs)
print('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')

cols = ['artikul_1', 'artikul_1', 'price_max', 'in_stock', 'city', 'desc']
df_fin = pd.concat([df, dfs], ignore_index=True, sort=False)[cols]


print('##############################')
print(df_fin)
print('##############################')
```

Comment: Сейчас добавлю ссылку на фалы на Я.диск
https://yadi.sk/d/_EWMHK9uo9KWsg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from pathlib import Path

mapping = {
    "Артикул ": "artikul_1",
    "Артикул аналог": "artikul_2",
    "Свободный остаток": "in_stock",
    "Номенклатура": "desc",
    "Москва": "сity",
}

p = Path(r"C:\temp\data")

cols = ['artikul_1', 'artikul_2', 'price_max', 'in_stock', 'city', 'desc']

df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f).rename(columns=mapping) 
                for f in p.glob("*.xls")], 
               sort=False)
```

Выбираем только те столбцы которые присутствуют в `cols`:

```
res = df.loc[:, df.columns.intersection(cols)]
```

Результат:

```
In [18]: res
Out[18]:
         artikul_1 artikul_2                                        desc in_stock
0   Ванны BelBagno       NaN                                         NaN      NaN
1              NaN       NaN                                         NaN      NaN
2             BB04       NaN               Акриловая ванна BELBAGNO BB04       20
3         BB04-ROS       NaN  Акриловая ванна BELBAGNO BB04-ROS, красный        3
4             BB05       NaN               Акриловая ванна BELBAGNO BB05    Много
5             BB07       NaN               Акриловая ванна BELBAGNO BB07        Р
6              NaN       NaN      Образец отделки акриловой ванны MARINE    Много
..             ...       ...                                         ...      ...
2              NaN   BB120SC                   ALBANO Сиденье, дюропласт      NaN
3              NaN  BB120CBR                  ALBANO Чаша безободкового       NaN
4              NaN  BB120CHR              ALBANO Чаша подвесного унитаза      NaN
5              NaN  BB120CPR           ALBANO Чаша унитаза безободкового      NaN
6              NaN   BB120CP         ALBANO Чаша унитаза, P-trap BB120CP      NaN
7          ALDINA        NaN                                         NaN      NaN
8              NaN   BB114SC                   ALDINA Сиденье, дюропласт      NaN

[37 rows x 4 columns]

In [19]: res.columns
Out[19]: Index(['artikul_1', 'artikul_2', 'desc', 'in_stock'], dtype='object')
```